# Question on dropping an object glued to another object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Let's say you glue a quarter to a $2×4$ board. Then, you drop the $2×4$ off a tall building and the board contacts the ground vertically (board perpendicular to the ground upon contact).

What force is experienced by the glue joint?

$\mathrm{F = m×a}$ where $\mathrm{a}$ is deacceleration upon contact. But, what mass? Is it the mass of the quarter or mass of the board?

Comment: If $F$ and $a$ are the force and acceleration of the glue, then $m$ is the mass of the glue. The force is going to be a complicated function of time, but you can calculate the average force using the average acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

It's the mass of the quarter.

That is, assuming it's the board that first makes contact with the ground and is decelerated.

In the unlikely event that the edge of the quarter hits an object, e.g. a box near the ground and the quarter makes contact first, then you'd need the mass of the board in the $F=ma$ equation.

As we can imagine, the quarter is more likely to come off the board in the second situation.

Comment: The board undergoes deacceleration too, so isn't there a force vector that would translate through the board too? How come this wouldn't impact the glue joint?

Comment: @benton98 The glue also has to be decelerated.  But the mass of glue is so small, we often ignore it.  The smaller the mass the smaller the force.

Comment: @benton98  Yes, the board decelerates first upon impact  (caused by a force from the ground on the board)- then if the coin is to stay in the same position relative to the board, it has to decelerate at the same rate.  The force that causes the coin to decelerate is from the glue between the board and coin.